# How to modify Active Server Page

Tags: asp-classic

I have done an Active Server Page. It is running on a foyerdisplay. The ASP is displaying meetings on that Display. I limited the displaying meetings to 10. The display can display 5-6 meeting at a time. What i want is that if the display is filled with the first 6 meetings the display should "change" to a second page which displays the last 4 meeting. That should happen every 10 seconds. 10 Seconds the first 6 meetings, 10 seconds the 4 meetings and so on. How can I do that?

My Code so far:

```html
<table cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:800px;">
<tr height="15"> <td colspan="6" class="underline"></td> </tr>
     <colgroup>
    <col  style="width:830px" >
  </colgroup>
    <tr><td> </td></tr>
 </table>

<table cellpadding="0" border = "1" style="background-color:white; dotted black;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:1270px;">


  <colgroup>
    <col  style="width:445px" >
    <col  style="width:275px" >
    <col  style="width:125px" >
    <col  style="width:125px" >
    <col  style="width:150px" >
    <col  style="width:150px" >
  </colgroup>

  <br></br>

  <tr style="background-color:blue; height="50">
                    <th align="left">Seminartitel</th> 
                    <th align="left">Zusatz-Info</th> 
                    <th align="absmiddle">von</th> 
                    <th align="absmiddle">bis</th> 
                    <th align="absmiddle">Gebäude</th> 
                    <th align="absmiddle">Raum</th> 

  </tr>
```

```vbs
<%
set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
set rsRaum=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")

rs.Open "select distinct buchung_id, von, bis, abteilung, veranstalter, THEMA, THEMA_ENABLED " & _
        "  from RESERVIERUNGRAUM r  " & _
        "      ,BUCHUNG b  " & _
        " where r.BUCHUNG_ID = b.ID " & _
        "   and von >= convert(date, getdate(), 4) " & _
        "   and von < convert(date, dateadd(day,1, GETDATE()), 4) " & _
        "   and BIS >= getdate() " & _
        "   and STORNO is null  " & _
        " order by von, bis" _
       ,objConn 

' Anzahl der darzustellenden Veranstaltungs-Zeilen
lineMax = 10
lineCount = 1
color = "color1"
do until rs.EOF

  ' Buchungen anzeigen oder nicht

  rsRaum.open "select DISPLAY_ENABLED from Buchung where ID = " & rs("buchung_id"), objConn
            displayanzeige = rsRaum("DISPLAY_ENABLED")
  rsRaum.close



  ' Hole für lfd. Buchung aus erster Reservierung Raum ID und Indikator für Kopplung 
  rsRaum.open "select raum_id, KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID from RESERVIERUNGRAUM where buchung_id = " & rs("buchung_id"), objConn
        raum_id = rsRaum("raum_id")
        KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID = rsRaum("KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID")
  rsRaum.close

   'Gebäude

  rsRaum.open      "select distinct g.BEZEICHNUNG " & _
                   "from GEBAEUDE g, ETAGE e, RAUM r " & _
                   "Where g.ID = e.GEBAEUDE_ID and e.GEBAEUDE_ID = r.GEBAEUDE_ID and r.ID = " & raum_id, objConn

                   GebaeudeBezeichnung = rsRaum("BEZEICHNUNG")

  rsRaum.close

  'Hole Terminal Hinweistext

  rsRaum.open    "select KSTR from Buchung where ID = " & rs("buchung_id"), objConn

                Hinweistext = rsRaum("KSTR")

  rsRaum.close


  ' falls Kopplung, hole ID des "Parent"-Raumes
  if not isNull( KOPPELBESTUHLUNG_ID ) then
    rsRaum.open "select parent_id from KOPPELN where CHILD_ID = " & raum_id, objConn
          if not rsRaum.EOF then
            raum_id = rsRaum("parent_id")
          end if
    rsRaum.close
  end if

  ' hole Raum Details
  rsRaum.open "select bezeichnung from Raum where ID = " & raum_id, objConn

      raumname = rsRaum("bezeichnung")

  rsRaum.close

  ' Beende, falls Display voll
  If lineCount > lineMax Then
    exit do
  End If 


  ' optionale Unterdrückung der Titelanzeige
  if ucase( rs("thema_enabled") ) = "Y" or isnull(rs("thema_enabled")) then
    thema = rs("thema")
  else
    thema = ""
  end if




  if ucase(displayanzeige) = "Y" or isnull(displayanzeige) then
%>
```

```html
  <tr "margin-bottom:100px" height="70" valign="top">
    <td style="overflow:hidden;" class="<% =color%>"><% =thema %></td>
    <td class="<% =color%>"><% =Hinweistext %></td>
    <td align="center"; class="<% =color%>"><% =FormatDateTime( rs("von"), 4)%></td>
    <td align="center"; class="<% =color%>"><% =FormatDateTime( rs("bis"), 4) %></td>
    <td align="center"; class="<% =color%>"><% =GebaeudeBezeichnung %><br></td>
    <td align="center"; class="<% =color%>"><% =raumname %><br></td>
  </tr>
```

```vbs
<%  

    ' jede zweite Zeile mit anderer Schriftfarbe

  If lineCount mod 2 = 1 Then
    color = "color2"
  Else
    color = "color1"
  End If
  lineCount = lineCount + 1


  end if
  rs.moveNext

loop
rs.close 
%>
```

How can I modify my Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a duplicate page and pass a parameter (`GET` or `POST`) to it as `RemainingItems` from current page. `RemainingItems` here is 4 and change the current page as following:

```
If lineCount > lineMax Then
```

TO be:

```
If lineCount > firstPageItems Then
```

obviously:

```
lineMax = firstPageItems + RemainingItems
```

For switching between pages, in specific intervals, you should use JavaScript timer on both pages. After time elapsed, redirect the client to the other page (each page knows the address of the other).

It is possible to do all the work in one page but since it need more work, according to question I suggest this one.